# PHP imagecopy function changing stamp size according to the main image height and width

Tags: php, php-gd

I'm trying to add a watermark (logo) to each image upload to the website.

So, I used imagecopy PHP function to add a watermark (a png image) to the main image (a jpg image) but the problem is the logo size is changing according to the main image size (height and width), That's mean if I upload a 4000x2000 image the logo with be somthing like 100x100 and if the main image size is 1000x500 the stamp will be bigger than the real size (546x537).

Image Samples:

```
https://crkemlak.com/appimg/199f8486d7d77007771f2f450dffca4d.jpeg
https://crkemlak.com/appimg/d6f9fd02999eced76eac9a6995df904f.jpeg
https://crkemlak.com/img/stamp.png
```

I used this code to add the watermark to the image:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('../appimg/'.$filenamerand);

$originalWidth= imagesx($im);
$originalHeight = imagesy($im);

$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('../img/stamp.png');
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);
imagecopy($im, $stamp, ($originalWidth-$sx)/2, ($originalHeight-$sy)/2, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
```

I need your help please to fix this problem, I need to make the watermark is in it's real size in any size of the main jpg image

Thanks

Comment: Write a function that takes the original image size as parameters, then use that to resize your water mark, then output the watermark for merging with the source image. Then the size of your source image doesn't change at all (unless you want it to of course).

Comment: @Difster Can you give me an examle please?

Comment: @GhadeerR.Majeed I don't get the logic, if the main images is bigger the stamp will be smaller?
Can you upload some working sample with the pics?

Comment: @PaulRM I updated the post, check it now please. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting 403 and put the link of the stamp too. ;-)

Comment: @PaulRM The website is working, check the update

Answer (score 0):

I used [imagecopyresized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) so that the watermark could be scaled to look the same on any input image irregardless of its size. Possibly better ways to do it. Im not sure how good the quality is when scaling images with transparent backgrounds. Here it is on [git](https://github.com/f13tv/watermarker)

```
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('main-image.jpg');

$wm_x = imagesx($watermark);
$wm_y = imagesy($watermark);
$img_x = imagesx($image);
$img_y = imagesy($image);

// calculate watermark size
$wm_scale = 19; // set size in relation to image
$wm_w = $img_x/$wm_scale;
$wm_aspect = $wm_y/$wm_x;
$wm_h = (int) ($wm_aspect * $wm_w);

// calculate margin
$margin_scale = 6; // set margin in relation to new watermark size
$margin_right = $wm_w/$margin_scale;
$margin_bottom = $wm_h/$margin_scale;

// calculate watermark destination
$dst_x = $img_x - $wm_w - $margin_right;
$dst_y = $img_y - $wm_h - $margin_bottom;

imagecopyresized ($image, $watermark, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $wm_w, $wm_h, $wm_x, $wm_y);

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```